# `for_each` not working as I expect

Tags: c++, algorithm, functional-programming, bind

I'm playing with some features of functional programming and am trying to call a member function for each object in a vector. Here's my code so far.

> emplace.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

class Person {
   public:
      Person(std::string name, size_t age) : _name(name), _age(age) { std::cout << "Hello, " << getName() << std::endl; }
      ~Person() { std::cout << "Goodbye, "<< getName() << std::endl; }
      void greet() { std::cout << getName() << " says hello!" << std::endl; }
      std::string getName() const { return _name; }
   private:
      std::string _name;
      size_t _age;

};

int main()
{
   std::vector<Person> myVector;
   myVector.emplace_back("Hello", 21);
   myVector.emplace_back("World", 20);

   std::for_each(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&Person::greet), this));
   return 0;
}
```

It's quite likely that there are problems with this code, but what is strange for me is the two error messages that I *am* getting.

```
emplace.cc:24:4: error: 'for_each' is not a member of 'std'
    std::for_each(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&Person::greet), this));
    ^
emplace.cc:24:95: error: invalid use of 'this' in non-member function
    std::for_each(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&Person::greet), this));
                                                                                               ^
```

I'm compiling with `-std=c++14` using GCC 5.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you forgot to include header `<algorithm>`. And you may not use `this` in this context.

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>


class Person {
   public:
      Person(std::string name, size_t age) : _name(name), _age(age) { std::cout << "Hello, " << getName() << std::endl; }
      ~Person() { std::cout << "Goodbye, "<< getName() << std::endl; }
      void greet() { std::cout << getName() << " says hello!" << std::endl; }
      std::string getName() const { return _name; }
   private:
      std::string _name;
      size_t _age;

};

int main()
{
   std::vector<Person> myVector;
   myVector.emplace_back("Hello", 21);
   myVector.emplace_back("World", 20);

   std::for_each(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), std::mem_fn( &Person::greet ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello, Hello
Hello, World
Goodbye, Hello
Hello says hello!
World says hello!
Goodbye, World
Goodbye, Hello
```

If you include the following call after the vector definition

```
std::vector<Person> myVector;
myVector.reserve( 2 );
```

then the output will be

```
Hello, Hello
Hello, World
Hello says hello!
World says hello!
Goodbye, World
Goodbye, Hello
```

that is the memory will not be reallocated when the second element is added.

Comment: Interesting. The destructor is called in the third line of output because I haven't implemented a move constructor, I suppose?

Comment: @erip  You did not reserve memory for two elements of the vector. So when the second element was added the vector reallocated its memory extent.

Comment: std::mem_f**u**n instead of fn?

Comment: No, it's [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn).

Comment: yeah. I didn't know about mem_fn. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`for_each` is in `<algorithm>`

You can do

```
for_each(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [&] (const decltype(myVector.front())& a) { a.greet(); });
```

Comment: I just added in how you can fix that :)

Comment: That's nice! I'll mark this as accepted. Is there a good way to do it with `bind`? It doesn't matter as long as it works, but just curious.

Comment: in c++14 lambda may be like this: [](auto el)
   {
    el.greet();
   }

Comment: I have never used `bind` before haha. But I think bind is used in a situation where you will not be providing the function arguments. But in `for_each` the function call to the third parameter is given an argument when called in it's implementation so I dont think you would want to use `bind` here. But maybe try removing `bind`?

Comment: @erip I don't think you need to bind. `std::for_each(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), std::mem_fun(&Person::greet));` should work. Also bind1st is deprecated now since c++11. Use bind and placeholder instead.

Comment: @Atomic_alarm yeah true haha I didn't realize he was using C++14... thats much cleaner syntax also! `decltype` just looks ugly