# Why doesn't std::for_each compile with minGW?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw

I'm trying to compile this line on Qt with MinGW compiler, using a `QVector<double>` and `std::for_each` function.

```
std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [max](double& n){ n/=max;});
```

I get this error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'for_each(QVector::iterator,   QVector::iterator, normalize(QVector&)::)'
>                          [max](double& n){ n/=max;});
>                                                    ^

**It compiles correctly with MVSC2013 32 bits.**

Comment: Did you include `<algorithm>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170248/for-each-not-working-as-i-expect/32170272#32170272

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. You must use C ++ 11.

Fixed by using C++ 11. Include: CONFIG += c++11 on .pro file.